# datatables change row background for row groups with equal column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

in my project there is a datatable showing some data using ajax server-side processing. I need to implement some sort of highlighting of rows with similar values of certain fields, but i am quite new to javascript and jquery, so i think i need a little help - didn't find any similar problem here.

I have 2 fields which i want to use in comparison - "Visitors" and "VisitDate", these are columns in my datatable. My goal is to set a random background color for the row GROUPS, where these column values are equal = visitors are equal to visitors AND visitDates are equal to visitDates.

I think i should use a "drawCallback" of datatables in my case, so here i am now:

```
drawCallback : function(settings) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows({page: 'current'}).nodes().to$();

            var groups = [];

            rows.each(function() {


            });


        },
```

Not very much, to be honest, but, as i mentioned above, i am quite new to all this jquery stuff. Please, tell me, what should i do to implement this? I need my table to be divided into groups, not sorted but only highlighted with background color, default color for the groups with only one element:

[image: example]

Thanks a lot for any help.

UPD. I need to do all this stuff for only one page which is currently displayed.

Comment: Way too much information is missing from your question to give a good answer to this complicated question. For instance: what I am worried about is the total number of rows in the table. If you use `drawCallback`, you need to compare each row to another. The number of these comparisons will quickly grow (n*n-n). So for 200 rows you will need to make 39,800 comparisons, and for 400 rows 159,600 comparisons. Not a good idea. So do the grouping in your database query, and perhaps even define the color there?

Comment: Thanks, i edited the question - i heen to do this for only one page which is currently displayed.